# Can't disable Windows Defender by using group policies

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, windows-defender

I have recently installed Win 10 Pro.
No matter how many times i try to disable Defender Antivirus with Group Policy Editor (Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Microsoft Defender Antivirus) by activating the policy "Turn off Windows Defender Antivirus" and clicking OK, Windows just ignores all my attempts and revert it back on like nothing happened...

It just turns Turn off Windows Defender Antivirus from enabled back to Not configured
When i close gpedit and open it back again i can see it's back to Not configured

Tamper Protection is off ...

I've been using PC's for 25 years without Antiviruses by using only common sense and Process Explorer.
Why is Microsoft forcing me to use something i don't want on my own computer?

Comment: You could run this command via PowerShell to disable Windows Firewall: **Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled False**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot completely disable Windows Defender.

You can turn much of it off, provided you install a good and reasonably well recognized Third Party Anti Virus. Just installing such a product will disable the Windows Defender Services it can.

With no Third Party AV, you must use and cannot disable Windows Defender.

It actually works well, is highly rated, and (on a good machine) does not use much resource.

Comment: that sounds like a nice excuse for taking the control out of hands of users and putting into hands of corporation, guess Microsoft is my nanny who knows better than me what i need

Comment: It is not an excuse - it is what Microsoft is doing to reduce overall problems for users. It actually works.

Comment: sure, just like any dictatorship